# codeigniter search function is not working

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, search, sql-like

I want to create simple search function. I follow some example. but I was unable to get results. please help me.

//control page

```
public function search(){

   $key = $this->input->post('phone1',TRUE);
   $data['ppp'] = $this->admin_model->searching($key);

    $this->load->view('members/search_result',$data);

}
```

//Model page

```
  public function searching($key){
              
     $this->db->like('phone1',$key);
     $query = $this->db->get('advertisement');
     return $query->result();
   }
```

Comment: <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($ppp as $ads){?>

                                    <tr class="active">
                                         <td><?php echo $ads->id;?></td>
                                         <td><?php echo $ads->status;?></td>
                                         <td><?php echo $ads->username;?></td>
                                        

                                    </tr>

 <?php } ?>
</tbody>

Comment: How are you calling the search? Can you edit the question and add html? Also, is there an error or something? how is it not working?

Comment: I want to find details from "advertisement" table by searching "phone" number. I tried to add html code. But I couldn't add since this website shows some errors when adding it.

Comment: <tbody> <?php foreach ($ppp as $ads){?> <tr class="active"> <td><?php echo $ads->id;?></td> <td><?php echo $ads->status;?></td> <td><?php echo $ads->username;?></td> </tr> <?php } ?> </tbody>

Comment: I have pasted html code in my last message.

Comment: I do not get any errors. But do not show any result by searching existing phone number

Comment: Can you show the `log_message` printing the $data?

Answer (score 0):

**try to print query**

```
    $query = $this->db->get('advertisement');
    echo $this->db->last_query();exit;
```

try and check that query in your database is that giving result or not